# If cassandra version is 2.2.12 at that time cqlsh is working, after updating latest version of cassandra (3.11.2v) cqlsh not working

Tags: sql, ubuntu, cassandra, cqlsh

I am new to cassandra database.if my cassandra version is 2.2.12 at that place cqlsh is working without any issues and it is connected.

after i updated my cassandra db 3.11.2 version, cqlsh is not connected throwing error

> Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})

after again i Downgrade my cassandra version cqlsh is working.
here why my latest cassandra cqlsh is not working.

Please help me,
Thank you

Comment: You need to check that your Cassandra is actually started... Check your logs for details

Comment: @AlexOtt ya cassandra is already started but its simply throwing above error.

Comment: Are you sure that it's running? It could start, but then finish its work - this happens quite often when it finds a problem reading some files. Check `system.log` for details.
Or it doesn't listen on localhost interface...

Comment: cassandra running status is   Active: active (exited)  . i don't know why its coming like this. even i checked cassandra.yml file. but my issue is not resolved.

Comment: Check lines above, especially with `ERROR` log level

Comment: in syslog file contains cassandra[12466]: start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 9923: No such process

Comment: No, please check `/var/log/cassandra/system.log` for these errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran the netstat command and got the following output:
below command is working for me check it once.

```
netstat -an | grep 9042 tcp 0 0 ::ffff:10.1.22.10:9042 :::* LISTEN The above output indicated that we are listening on port 9042 and IP address 10.1.22.10.
```

However, the error clearly showed that cqlsh was trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 by default. So we were getting "connection refused" error.

Modified the cqlsh command to connect to the IP address 10.1.22.10 and re-ran it as follows and we were able to connect to Cassandra database successfully.